# How to retain two decimal points in flex using Math.round()

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

How to retain two decimal points in flex using Math.Round

code:

```
txtTotal.text=Math.round((Number(txtRate.text)*Number(txtQuantity.text))).toString();
```

here the rate is a constant 1.1 and quantity is variable 
 ie rate*quantity=1.1 * quantity

Comment: Floating point numbers do not have a "fixed" fractional part. You want to *format* the number as text that shows two digits. In JavaScript (and thus AS?) `Number.toFixed(2)` (e.g. `(123.456).toFixed(2)`) is what you are looking for ..

Comment: Yes you are right we can use tofixed() it is showing correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.toString()`, use `.toFixed(2)`;

Comment: Above is best way to fix your problem. but still you can also use this solution
 `var temp:Number = Math.round((Number(txtRate.text)*Number(txtQuantity.text)) * 100) /100;`
`txtTotal.text = temp.toString();`

Comment: .toFixed(2) fix is good but if you are using some calculation that time(like addition or for percentage calculation - 100%) there might be difference, solution provided by "JK Patel" is more appropriate as it will work in all scenario - as i have faced lot of problem because of .toFixed(2) specially when you are using charts.